# android Listview onItemClick fill EditText

Tags: java, android, android-listview, onclicklistener

I'm working on a small program to text voice recognition, the issue is that the voice recognition is filling a listView, which is good, now i want to fill an EditText with the contents of the clicked ListView item:
my code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE)
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            ArrayList<String> textMatchList = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

            if (!textMatchList.isEmpty()) {
                mlvTextMatches.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                    textMatchList));


            }
        }

    mlvTextMatches.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
            //Not Sure what to do here!
            EditText InputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inptWord);
        }
    });
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}`
```

Any ideas?

Comment: after initializing your editText, try to add this code: `InputText.setText( textMatchList.get(position))`

Comment: yes that worked for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `textMatchList` a member variable:

```
ArrayList<String> textMatchList = new ArrayList<String>();

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
    if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE)
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            textMatchList = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
    ...
    ...
    mlvTextMatches.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
            EditText InputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inptWord);
            InputText.setText(textMatchList.get(position));
        }
    });
}
```

The `position` parameter of the `onItemClick` method represents the position of the clicked list item.